# how to split a list to multiple partitions and sent to executors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

When we use spark to read data from csv for DB as follow, it will automatically split the data to multiple partitions and sent to executors

```
spark
  .read
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .option("codec", properties.getProperty("sparkCodeC"))
  .format(properties.getProperty("fileFormat"))
  .load(inputFile)
```

Currently, I have a id list as :

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...1000]
```

What I want to do is split this list to multiple partitions and sent to executors, in each executor, run the sql as

```
ids.foreach(id => {    
select * from table where id = id
})
```

When we load data from cassandra, the connector will generate the query sql as:

```
select columns from table where Token(k) >= ? and Token(k) <= ?
```

it means, the connector will scan the whole database, virtually, I needn't to scan the whole table, I just what to get all the data from the table where the k(partition key) in the id list.

the table schema as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab.events (
    k int,
    o text,
    event text
    PRIMARY KEY (k,o)
);
```

or how can i use spark to load data from cassandra using pre defined sql statement without scan the whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use [`joinWithCassandra` function](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12) to perform selection only of the data is required for your operation.  But be aware that this function is only available via RDD API.

Something like this:

```
val joinWithRDD = your_df.rdd.joinWithCassandraTable("tab","events")
```

You need to make sure that column name in your DataFrame matched the partition key name in Cassandra - see documentation for more information.

The DataFrame implementation is only available in the DSE version of Spark Cassandra Connector as described in [following blog post](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/23/DSEDirectJoin/).

Update in September 2020th: support for join with Cassandra was added in the [Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all)